# How to make a deep copy of lucene TokenStream object

Tags: solr, lucene

I am trying to create a custom solr filter which will keep only the token that has maximum integer value. In doing so, I have written the following code so far:

```java
public final class MaxValueTokenFilter extends TokenFilter {

    private final CharTermAttribute termAttribute = addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);  

    public MaxValueTokenFilter(TokenStream in) {
        super(in);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean incrementToken() throws IOException {

        TokenStream clonedTokenStream = DeepCopy???(input);

        int maxVal = 0;

        //increamenting the clonedTokenStream should not increment the actual tokenStream
        while (clonedToken.incrementToken()) {      
            final String term = termAttribute.toString();      
            int currentNumber = Integer.parseInt(term);
            if(currentNumber > maxVal)
            {       
                maxVal = currentNumber;  
            }
        }

        //increment the actual token to match the maximum value
        while (input.incrementToken()) {        
            final String term = termAttribute.toString();      
            int currentNumber = Integer.parseInt(term);
            if(currentNumber == maxVal)
            {       
                return true;    
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void reset() throws IOException {
        super.reset();
    }
}
```

Can somebody help me to make the DeepCopy of the TokenStream object so that incrementing the copied TokenStream does not increment the actual TokenStream.